# Count number of methods in a MATLAB class

Tags: matlab

Is there a quick way to count the number of methods in a MATLAB class ?

```
obj = myClassName()
```

Is there a way to get the number of methods inside this class?

Comment: I have edited your question to make sure the terminology holds correctly. I did this because I think this is a quite interesting question and a proper statement of it will help finding it and will be very helpful for the whole community. If you don't like the edits, please put it as it was.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer that most helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! At least in MatlabR2014b you can use [`methods`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/methods.html)

example:

```
methods('SURFPoints')
```

or

```
methods('myClassName')
```

Probably you would be able to find it with a quick google but you mix your terminology a bit. `myClassName()` is a **class**, and all the functions that are specific of this class and are "inside" it are called **methods**. Do not call method to a class! There is nothing like "number of functions used in a method" (well, there is but its definitely not what you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
a = ?MyClassName;
numMethods = numel(a.MethodList);
```

Here `a` is a metaclass object that contains all the details of the class `MyClassName`, such as its package, properties, methods, events etc.